# how to set sliding tabbar y position little bit sown

Tags: ios, tabbar

https://github.com/EuanChan/XSlidableTabController
From there i download one demo sliding Tabbar but in this demo i want tabbar position little bit down because i want set one image, label and back button top of page  but i can't able to find to set tabbar position , 
and i hide navigation bar its automatically on set top i want to little bit down

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

[image]

BUT i want to set image top of tabbar 
please Help me , please share your valuable knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps.

1. open **XSlidableTabController.m**
2. go to `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` method

add below code at last

```
// change 20 to any other what ever you want.
[_tabView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, _tabHeight)];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_tabView];
```

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `baseY` value in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method in XSlidableTabController.m.
[image]

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
CGFloat baseY = 60.0f, width = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGRect rtTabMenu = CGRectMake(0, baseY, width, _tabHeight);
[_tabView setFrame:rtTabMenu];
baseY += rtTabMenu.size.height;
CGRect rtContent = CGRectMake(0, baseY, width, self.view.frame.size.height - baseY);
[_scrollView setFrame:rtContent];
CGSize szScrollContent = _scrollView.contentSize;
szScrollContent.height = rtContent.size.height;
[_scrollView setContentSize:szScrollContent];
}
```

Comment: it will take down whole controller. he want to take down only tab.